# How to Select the Joins?Right or Left

Tags: sql

How to decide the tables which is left and which is right while querying it using joins?Is there any Thumb Rule.

Comment: Most people use *left join* because the 1st table is usually the most important one. The *right join* is actually not needed (exists probably only to complete the syntax) and can be rewritten.

Comment: And it's much easier to understand `main table left join optional data`, instead of `optional data right join main table`.

Comment: My question is how can i know the table is in left or right?is that some thing like master table should be on left and transnational one should be on right?

Comment: PRO TIP: **never use RIGHT JOIN**. Its confusing and mostly always useless. Always start with the table that contains the "core" data you want to retrieve, and add LEFT JOINS to it.

Comment: Thanks Thomas,i could get little clarity now.So according to the your Statement, kind of Master Table should be considered as the left table while quering.right?

Comment: That's right. The RIGHT might be helpfull during coding, whenever you think that you have chosen the wrong  table as the main table. In that case you can quickly change the LEFT to RIGHT just to test. But after that, if it comes that you were wrong, you should have the discipline to adapt your query to a LEFT JOIN again, by interverting the 2 tables. Try to never let RIGHT joins in your finished code. It works fine for the machine, but it's harder for the human brain, and especially on heavy queries involving a lot of tables.

Answer (score 0):

"left" is that table  which appears first after the FROM clause when reading from left to right
example:

```
 select t1.* ,t2.* from table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id
```

here table1 is left table